# How do I get last login unix timestamp for a user using kernel API (not `last` cmd)

Tags: kernel, api

I want to write a program that can get information about a user, specifically last login time in unix timestamp format using kernel API (not using any shell cmd). What function do I need to call to get that information?

Comment: Logging in is a user space context, the kernel has no notion of that. All you could do is ask it to log any time a process changes uid, euid, gid, egid, supplementary groups or changes its working directory to a user's home directory which are some of the things that happen when a user logs in.

Comment: `s/context/concept/` sorry above.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you write that you "want to write a program" - in what language?

Answer (score 2):

The kernel does *not* do that and has *no* APIs for that. In fact the Linux kernel all by itself does literally nothing, except initializing *some* of your devices on boot and then launching `/sbin/init`. Perhaps you meant **system APIs** in which case you're welcome to stackoverflow.com

You could also simply check the `last` utility source code. It's also worth noting that the `last` utility does not always log logins, e.g. here on Fedora I use the `lxdm` display manager and it [doesn't write](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1739494) to `/var/log/wtmp`, i.e my logins are not saved.

Comment: Thanks I used [`utmp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) entry to get the data, It works fine.